# Why this code not continue?

Tags: c, save, cycle, scanf

I would like to know why this code does not start from the word that is stored in the file.txt.

The code compiles but can not find the error

I wonder why the function "scanf" fails to capture the characters and passes them to the variable

Thanks for responding

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int e = 0;
    int f = 0;
    int g = 0;
    int h = 0;

    char var[] = { '1', 'A', '2', 'B', '3', 'C', '4', 'D', '5', 'E', '6' };
    char caracteres[9];
    char caracteres_txt[9];


    FILE *fp, *sesion;
    sesion = fopen("Save_Sesion.txt", "r");

    if (sesion == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nNo sesion saved.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nlast word was:\n\n");
        fgets(caracteres, 9, sesion);
        printf("%s\n", caracteres);
        fscanf(sesion, "%s", caracteres_txt);
    }


    if (caracteres_txt[1] == var[0])
    {
        a = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (caracteres_txt[1] == var[1])
        {
            a = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (caracteres_txt[1] == var[2])
            {
                a = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                if (caracteres_txt[1] == var[3])
                {
                    a = 3;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (caracteres_txt[1] == var[4])
                    {
                        a = 4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (caracteres_txt[1] == var[5])
                        {
                            a = 5;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (caracteres_txt[1] == var[6])
                            {
                                a = 6;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (caracteres_txt[1] == var[7])
                                {
                                    a = 7;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (caracteres_txt[1] == var[8])
                                    {
                                        a = 8;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (caracteres_txt[1] == var[9])
                                        {
                                            a = 9;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            if (caracteres_txt[1] == var[10])
                                            {
                                                a = 10;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    if (caracteres_txt[2] == var[0])
    {
        b = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (caracteres_txt[2] == var[1])
        {
            b = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (caracteres_txt[2] == var[2])
            {
                b = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                if (caracteres_txt[2] == var[3])
                {
                    b = 3;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (caracteres_txt[2] == var[4])
                    {
                        b = 4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (caracteres_txt[2] == var[5])
                        {
                            b = 5;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (caracteres_txt[2] == var[6])
                            {
                                b = 6;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (caracteres_txt[2] == var[7])
                                {
                                    b = 7;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (caracteres_txt[2] == var[8])
                                    {
                                        b = 8;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (caracteres_txt[2] == var[9])
                                        {
                                            b = 9;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            if (caracteres_txt[2] == var[10])
                                            {
                                                b = 10;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (caracteres_txt[3] == var[0])
    {
        c = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (caracteres_txt[3] == var[1])
        {
            c = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (caracteres_txt[3] == var[2])
            {
                c = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                if (caracteres_txt[3] == var[3])
                {
                    c = 3;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (caracteres_txt[3] == var[4])
                    {
                        c = 4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (caracteres_txt[3] == var[5])
                        {
                            c = 5;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (caracteres_txt[3] == var[6])
                            {
                                c = 6;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (caracteres_txt[3] == var[7])
                                {
                                    c = 7;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (caracteres_txt[3] == var[8])
                                    {
                                        c = 8;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (caracteres_txt[3] == var[9])
                                        {
                                            c = 9;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            if (caracteres_txt[3] == var[10])
                                            {
                                                c = 10;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (caracteres_txt[4] == var[0])
    {
        d = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (caracteres_txt[4] == var[1])
        {
            d = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (caracteres_txt[4] == var[2])
            {
                d = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                if (caracteres_txt[4] == var[3])
                {
                    d = 3;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (caracteres_txt[4] == var[4])
                    {
                        d = 4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (caracteres_txt[4] == var[5])
                        {
                            d = 5;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (caracteres_txt[4] == var[6])
                            {
                                d = 6;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (caracteres_txt[4] == var[7])
                                {
                                    d = 7;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (caracteres_txt[4] == var[8])
                                    {
                                        d = 8;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (caracteres_txt[4] == var[9])
                                        {
                                            d = 9;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            if (caracteres_txt[4] == var[10])
                                            {
                                                d = 10;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    printf("\nPress Enter to continue\n");
    getchar();


    while (a <= 10)
    {
        while (b <= 10)
        {
            while (c <= 10)
            {
                while (d <= 10)
                {
                    while (e <= 10)
                    {
                        while (f <= 10)
                        {
                            while (g <= 10)
                            {
                                while (h <= 10)
                                {
                                    printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n", var[a],
                                           var[b], var[c], var[d], var[e],
                                           var[f], var[g], var[h]);
                                    ++h;
                                }
                                h = 0;
                                ++g;
                            }
                            g = 0;
                            ++f;
                        }
                        f = 0;
                        ++e;
                    }
                    e = 0;
                    ++d;
                    fp = fopen("Save_Sesion.txt", "w");
                    fprintf(fp, "%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n", var[a], var[b], var[c],
                            var[d], var[e], var[f], var[g], var[h]);
                    fclose(fp);
                }
                d = 0;
                ++c;
            }
            c = 0;
            ++b;
        }
        b = 0;
        ++a;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You really need to use some loop constructs, like `for` or `while` as it would eliminate a lot of the `if`/`else` constructs and greatly simplify the code. What does your `Save_Sesion.txt` contents look like?

Comment: Save_Sesion.txt contains the last sentence generated approximately every 14,000 interactions

thanks for answering

Comment: Could you show an example so it is clear what `fgets` and `fscanf` are trying to read? Maybe a couple of lines from the beginning of the file?

Comment: You can try to merge multiple if statements using a switch statement. Your code would be more readable.

Comment: What I need to read with fscanf are the first 4 characters.
If the phrase is saved every 14000 iterations, the last 4 characters never change.

Comment: It's not a good idea to name the first parameter of `main` with `main`, we choose `argc` as convention.

Comment: Oops! I'm sorry I did wrong the copy-paste...the code have int main(int argc ,char *argv[]){

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself

The solution is not to use fgets and fscan together ....not the if-else constructs.